# PHP: How to access object inside class

Tags: php, oop

I have a language class with public data members:

```
class language {
    public $error = "There was an error";
}
```

Then I have many different classes that uses this class. How can I access this class from within other classes? You could of course instantiate an object of it inside all the classes that uses it, but I suppose that would drastically decrease the performance, if I were to do that with multiple classes.

I do only need one object, since I don't change them anyway. So, I've done

```
$language = new language();

class name {
    private $language;

    public function __construct() {
        global $language;
        $this->language = $language;
    }


    public function method() {
        mysql_query(...) or die($this->language->error);
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to do it? Now I have to instantiate it in every "mother" script. And I suppose by doing __construct() I'm only passing a refrence, since I don't use the clone word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do only need one object

This is the Singleton pattern.

Here is a quick example of a way to have only one instance of your Language class:

```
class Language {
  public $error = "text";

  private static $instance = null;

  public static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance == null)
      self::$instance = new self();
    return self::$instance;
  }

  private function __construct() {}
}

$lang = Language::getInstance();
$text = $lang->error;
```

You can also use dependency injection:

```
interface ILanguage {
  public function getError();
}

class Language implements ILanguage {
  private $error = "error";
  public function getError() {
    return $this->error;
  }
}

class name {
  private $language;

  public function __construct(ILanguage $lang) {
    $this->language = $lang;
  }

   public function method() {
     mysql_query(...) or die($this->language->getError());
   }
}

$language = new Language();
$n = new name($language);
```

This example of dependency injection is called [constructor injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorInjectionWithPicocontainer).

Comment: Aha, is this a common known "rule" or "pattern"? $lang = Language::getInstance(); passes a reference, not the object itself?

Comment: Yes this is a common Design Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern Here the object is not copied because as mentioned in this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php 'When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.'

Comment: @DanLee this is a highly subjective point of view, you should have it phrased it differently: "some people, such as dependency injection advocates, consider the singleton pattern as an anti-pattern"

Comment: @SirDarius yeah you are right it is my point of view. But I can't take "making everything global" (that's what it basically is) as a serious pattern. Then we all could stick to functions and the `global` keyword. I like the hierarchies in OOP, because you know on what you can rely and on what not.

Comment: @SirDarius How does for example WordPress or Joomla! do it? Doesn't getInstance need to be static for this to work?

Comment: yup it does ! editing my sample ! (PHP does not enforce the use of the static keyword, as long as $this is not used in the method) but I'm adding it for clarity and correctness

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts I don't know about Joomla, but Wordpress is really good example of bad code. There are thousands of functions (no methods, because the lack of classes) thrown together, and only a few people seem to understand the "core" (if you can call it like that). To your second question: Yes it'd need to be static.

Comment: Well, WordPress was a bad example then. But, how do the "big guys" do it?

Comment: Singletons have their place for things that really need to have one and only one instance (like safety regulation in a nuclear reactor). There are very few instances I've seen in PHP that absolutely require a singleton. For one, singletons can make it extremely hard to test your code. See my answer for some alternative suggestions. The Service Locator especially is a good replacement for singletons as it's usage is fairly similar and vastly increases the testability of code.

Comment: @DanLee yeah, I kind of agree with you on the issue of globality, but we are talking about PHP, the language with hundreds of global functions with no parameter ordering convention :)

Comment: StudentofHogwarts Well I often saw singletons in companies, because they are very convenient to use. But I personally recommend dependency injection. (maybe have a look at Symfony 2) @SirDarius then we better fight against the mess, instead of making it worse :)

Comment: @DanLee Well said. See my answer!

Comment: answer now improved with dependency injection example

Comment: @SirDarius: That is another option, but I personally think throwing $language over to all the different objects is a little cumbersome. Can one say that using language::$value is the best method?

Answer (score 2):

Basically your language object is a dependency of your other objects. There are a number of factors you need to consider:
- performance (how wise it is to instantiate a new language object each time you need it, or whether that is even possible)
- testing - how you could test your classes if each one has a hard-coded dependency on your language class
- maintainability/readability.

There are various different solutions to the problem. The one that seems to be most in fashion in the PHP community is the Dependency Injection Container. This can be a good solution if you are in a greenfield situation.

A good article on the general subject is [one by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (who else?).

EDIT: To explain a bit more the article deals with the Inversion of Control principle. I won't explain it in depth as I don't think I could do it as well as Martin Fowler amongst others but the nub of it is that your classes do not manage their own dependencies; that is done elsewhere (hence the name Inversion of Control). There are broadly two different ways of doing it - Dependency Injection (which may or may not involve a Container) and Service Locator. This [section](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#DecidingWhichOptionToUse) of Martin Fowler's article deals with some of the differences between the two.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain it here?

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts I've added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Can you add an example in PHP?

Comment: That's,probably beyond the scope of SO. Maybe go and read some articles about it, have a go and post a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the `Language` object in the constructor of your class:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->language = new Language();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that slow down the script, and use unnecessary amounts of memory? I don't need to change what's inside the language class at run time anyway.

Comment: So it'll make a separate object for every class that have errors or outputs anything.

Comment: If what you need is a "global" object, you might consider to write `Language` class as [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: Accept one answer and you'll get 2 rep points, then you will have 15

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to have instances of this class, consider making its properties and methods `static`:

```
class language {
    static public $error = "There was an error";
}
```

then use them statically:

```
$error = language::$error;
```

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. I didn't know that it worked that way. I thought a static was something that the objects shared.. What do you think is the best method? I'm completely new to OOP, and just thought about that instantiating an object more times than nececcary would slow down the script?

Comment: `static` properties and methods belong to the class itself, not to its instances. They are "shared" between the instances only in the sense that they can access them via the `self` pseudo-class. You access static properties as `Class::$property` and static methods as `Class::method()`. What you need in your case is either a [Sintlegon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), or a class with static properties like this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global variable, you could pass it via constructor.

```
public function __construct($language) {
    $this->language = $language;
}
```